# Creating VB code to extract an email address from the body of a message in Outlook

Tags: php, vba, vb.net, outlook

Let me explain what I need to do:

PROBLEM:

I receive emails for online orders that go into a specific email inbox in Outlook and I would like to send an automatic response to the senders letting them know that their order was received.  The issue is this: the senders email is NOT in the from field, it is in the body of the email - the from field is populated with our webadmin address (email orders are generated via an online form from our school website and sent from a centralized account.)  As such an automatic rule simply send an email response to the web admin email account and not the actual order.

Email Specifics:

All of these emails have the same subject line.  All of the emails with this subject line are filtered into the folder "Online Orders - Incoming" All of the emails are required to have the senders email address in the body; here is an actual email  (sensitive information is x'ed out - email address is at the end):

=================================================================

PRINT REQUEST:

Print Job Name :   Accounting Majors
Department:
AccountNo:         xxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx 
FileNo:

Date_In:           08-22-2013

Date_Needed:       08-24-2013

Num_Originals:     2

Num_Copies:        40

Finished_Copy:     Front and Back

Paper_Color:       Green

Paper_Stock:       None

Finished_Size:     8 1/2  x  11

Carbonless_Choice: None

Bindery_Choice:    None

Ink Color:         Use black ink

Special Instructions:

Thanks,
xxxxxx xxxxxx **SENDERSREALEMAILADDRESS@xxx.edu**

Phone: ext. XXXX 
Fax: ext. XXXX

======================================================================

I'm very new to VB but I'm capable of learning but I haven't had much luck getting started.  What I would like to do is generate an email to the embedded email address in the order form and have the email include a simple message letting our customer know that we have received their order.

If anyone can offer me any help with this I would be very grateful.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could put the body in a string, tokenize it into a string array with `Strings.Split(emailBody)` and then iterate through the array looking for @ and . in the same string. Something like `If strArr(index).Contains("@") AndAlso strArr(index).Contains(".") Then ...`

Comment: You should post some code to show us what you have already done in an attempt to solve your problem.

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking.  My issue at this point is I have no experience with Visual Basic and I'm literally coming at it completely green.

What I have is very generic thus far.  I'm pretty sure I can figure out how to have it look for a particular subject, a particular Email Folder and generate the email I want.  This is all pretty basic.   I'm completely stumped on how to code it to look for an email address in the body and insert it into the TO field in the generated email.

This is super generic, but it's where I'm at:

Comment: I have no idea how to get the code to format correctly in this discussion.  Sorry

Comment: Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items  
Public Sub Application_Startup()
' Reference the items in the Inbox. Because myOlItems is declared
' "WithEvents" the ItemAdd event will fire below.
Set myOlItems = Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub
Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
If Item.Subject = "Print Center Online Order Form" Then
' Here's where I think I should set the code '
End If
End If
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the email body (on spaces) into an array, and then checking each element of the array for an @ sign and period.
Something like this:

```
For Each Sec in Strings.Split(Item.Body)
  If Sec.Contains("@") And Sec.Contains(".") Then
    ''At this point, Sec contains the email address. Do something here.

    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

To get the emails in a custom folder, try this:

```
Set Items = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Print Center").Items
```

Or in a custom sub-folder:

```
Set Items = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Print Center").Folders("Online Oredrs - Incoming").Items
```

Comment: Thanks - I will work with that and then repost my results later.  This is not a pressing issue but it's something that would be nice for us to provide to our customers and I'd like to start wrapping my head around VB anyway so, what better what to learn? :)  

I'll let you know how this goes and thanks again for the help.

Comment: Does anyone have any advise as to how I would make the macro look in a user defined folder?  The folder name is "Online Oredrs - Incoming" wich is located under the group folder "Print Center.  The Print Center folders is on the same level as the Inbox, outbox etc..